# Query is too long

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have this query for counting data on my database's table and store it to a textbox, then save it to another table where it stores the count. I stored the data to my textboxes first because i need to put the count on their specific locations on my second database table. Is there any way to simplify this query? :

```
query = "SELECT (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Revenue Assurance') as [Revenue Assurance]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department Like '%Compliance, Fraud Investigation Services%' OR (Department = 'Compliance, Fraud Investigation Services')) as [Compliance, Fraud Investigation Services]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department Like '%Compliance, Solutions and Services%' OR (Department = 'Compliance, Solutions and Services')) as [Compliance, Solutions and Services]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Revenue Assurance' AND (P_Level = 'Head (Senior)')) as [txtRAHS]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Revenue Assurance' AND (P_Level = 'Head')) as [txtRAH]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Revenue Assurance' AND (P_Level = 'Sr. Manager')) as [txtRASRMGR]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Revenue Assurance' AND (P_Level = 'Manager')) as [txtRAMGR]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Revenue Assurance' AND (P_Level = 'Sr. Supervisor')) as [txtRASRSUP]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Revenue Assurance' AND (P_Level = 'Supervisor')) as [txtRASUP]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Revenue Assurance' AND (P_Level = 'Jr. Supervisor')) as [txtRAJRSUP]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Revenue Assurance' AND (P_Level = 'Sr. Staff')) as [txtRASRSTF]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Revenue Assurance' AND (P_Level = 'Staff')) as [txtRASTF]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Revenue Assurance' AND (P_Level = 'Jr. Staff')) as [txtRAJRSTF]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Revenue Assurance' AND (P_Level = 'Project Staff')) as [txtRAPS]" & _
'[CFIS]
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Compliance, Fraud Investigation Services' AND (P_Level = 'Head')) as [txtCFISH]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Compliance, Fraud Investigation Services' AND (P_Level = 'Sr. Manager')) as [txtCFISSRMGR]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Compliance, Fraud Investigation Services' AND (P_Level = 'Manager')) as [txtCFISMGR]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Compliance, Fraud Investigation Services' AND (P_Level = 'Sr. Supervisor')) as [txtCFISSRSUP]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Compliance, Fraud Investigation Services' AND (P_Level = 'Supervisor')) as [txtCFISSUP]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Compliance, Fraud Investigation Services' AND (P_Level = 'Jr. Supervisor')) as [txtCFISJRSUP]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Compliance, Fraud Investigation Services' AND (P_Level = 'Sr. Staff')) as [txtCFISSRSTF]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Compliance, Fraud Investigation Services' AND (P_Level = 'Staff')) as [txtCFISSTF]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Compliance, Fraud Investigation Services' AND (P_Level = 'Jr. Staff')) as [txtCFISJRSTF]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Compliance, Fraud Investigation Services' AND (P_Level = 'Project Staff')) as [txtCFISPS]" & _
'[CSS]
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Compliance, Solutions and Services' AND (P_Level = 'Head')) as [txtCSSH]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Compliance, Solutions and Services' AND (P_Level = 'Sr. Manager')) as [txtCSSSRMGR]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Compliance, Solutions and Services' AND (P_Level = 'Manager')) as [txtCSSMGR]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Compliance, Solutions and Services' AND (P_Level = 'Sr. Supervisor')) as [txtCSSSRSUP]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Compliance, Solutions and Services' AND (P_Level = 'Supervisor')) as [txtCSSSUP]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Compliance, Solutions and Services' AND (P_Level = 'Jr. Supervisor')) as [txtCSSJRSUP]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Compliance, Solutions and Services' AND (P_Level = 'Sr. Staff')) as [txtCSSSRSTF]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Compliance, Solutions and Services' AND (P_Level = 'Staff')) as [txtCSSSTF]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Compliance, Solutions and Services' AND (P_Level = 'Jr. Staff')) as [txtCSSJRSTF]," & _
" (SELECT COUNT (Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Department = 'Compliance, Solutions and Services' AND (P_Level = 'Project Staff')) as [txtCSSPS]" & _
" From tblEmployees"
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not count and group by department and level...

Comment: Agreed with @ta.speot.is , and if those aliases are important (txtxxxxx) to what you're doing, you can always make a table that stores them and relates them with each department / level combination, so that you can join to it when you run such a query.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks. but how do i group them by dept and level? sorry such a noob :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select department, p_level, count(*) as num_employees
from tblemployees
group by department, p_level
```

To get the count of employees by department and p_level (all combinations)

If you need to have those aliases returned on each row, create another table in your database, three columns:

department,
p_level,
count_alias

Put each department and p_level combination onto one row, and your alias into the count_alias column.

Then, when you run the query I gave you, join tblemployees to the above 3 column table (using department and p_level) and return the count_alias.

Comment: Hi @ShWiVeL , sorry i don't get what you said. :( can u explain it more? . sorry

Comment: @JgzTradamus If the result of that query alone is good enough for you, then that's all you need. In your query you gave a unique name (such as txtRASRMGR, txtRAJRSUP, etc.) to a variety of different department and p_level combinations, I assume because your application uses the aliases elsewhere. So if it's important that you identify each count with such an alias, you could make a table to store the aliases and then relate them to this result. You'll only have to do that if having those aliases is important though.

Comment: It seems like it is important because i need those aliases to store the count to my textboxes. How do i relate them? sorry for a noob question, i don't know a lot in writing queries :(

Comment: Create a 2nd table with 3 columns (department, p_level, count_alias) and fill it in (create one row for each department and p_level combination, with the count_alias column being your alias for that combination). Then run the same select query as above, but join to that table on department and p_level, and return the 2nd table's (the one you're creating) count_alias column.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL IN clause

e.g.

```
SELECT
  P_Level,
  COUNT(Employee_Name) AS COUNT_Employee_Name,
FROM tblEmployees
WHERE Department = 'Revenue Assurance'
  AND P_Level IN ('Head (Senior)', 'Head', 'Sr. Manager', 'Manager', 'Sr. Supervisor', 'Supervisor' ... )
GROUP BY P_Level
```

Comment: with that query where the count be stored?.

Comment: @Jgz Tradamus COunt return from select just like any other SQL query? What are you expecting?